# basis of k-vector space V depending on characteristic of K

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a field and $V=K^3$
$$B = \lbrace f_1 = (1,2,3),f_2=(-1,2,4),f_3=(2,1,5)\rbrace$$
for what characteristic of K is $B$ a basis of $V$.

I am not really sure how to approach this question besides trying different cases for the characteristic of K but that does not seem to be the right way to approach this question for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The determinant has to be non-zero in characteristic k, for it to be a basis.

Can you find the determinant of the matrix spanned by those vectors?